# JSON object in IE6 - How?

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

Quick questions that probably a piece of cake for someone in the know to asnwer.

I have a simple asp.net website that uses JSON for a bunch of stuff (and JSON.stringify)

All good in firefox etc, yet, in IE6 I run into an error with JSON being undefined.

Is there a way I can include a JSON implementation without breaking what I have already (using the native JSON objects in the other browsers).
If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it you're using? http://json.org/json2.js ?

Comment: Or are you not using any library and expecting `JSON.stringify` to exist?

Comment: sounds like he might be relying on native JSON support in the browser, if it works in Firefox and not in IE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_JSON_in_Firefox

Comment: @Russ: probably, yes. I'd assume OP would say both IE6 and 7 don't work then.

Comment: yep - Ive not tried IE7 but I am using the browsers built in JSON object.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The json2 library at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js is exactly what you're looking for. You can include it unconditionally, and it adds JSON.parse and JSON.stringify to your global namespace (only if there isn't one defined yet). It won't mess with any built-in JSON. From its source:

```
if (!this.JSON) {
    this.JSON = {};
}
...
if (typeof JSON.stringify !== 'function') {
...
if (typeof JSON.parse !== 'function') {
```

That's comprehensive! Even if for some reason you already have JSON.stringify but not JSON.parse (or vice versa) it'll still do the right thing, leaving the original ones in place.

Comment: link is throwing error atm.  So here's a backup https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 4):

Your version of firefox might be having built-in support for the JSON library. But ideally you should include the JSON js library from json.org (make a copy of it in your hosted domain).

Comment: Yes and I think recent versions of the json library detect if there's a native json to use.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this issue, you can load json2.js before using JSON. refer to this [link](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSON-js made avaliable on Github by Douglas Crockford it makes the JSOn object avaliable in browsers which dont support the JSOn object natively just include a single js file in ur page which uses JSOn object. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Also Check out this link http://json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for `JSON.stringify` and if it doesn't exist, use some other method to parse data into a JSON string.