# IE6 JSON is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-6

I am using ajax with Jquery to call my c# web methods. These work great in IE8, firefox etc but comes up with this error in IE6.

Anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON object in IE6 - How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787020/json-object-in-ie6-how)

Comment: you're going to have to show us some code. you haven't given use anything like enough information to help you.

Comment: nothing before you share some code and the actual error message you get.

Comment: JSON is undefined in IE6 and IE7 not matter what code you try and run. The dogged pleas for code here are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE6/7 does not have a native JSON parser. The following adds this functionality to lesser equipped browsers.

https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js